# How to deal with "statistics classes mismatched" error when imported tsfile to different server in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

> ERROR o.a.i.d.e.c.l.LevelCompactionTsFileManagement:696 - Error
> occurred in Compaction Merge thread
> org.apache.iotdb.tsfile.exception.filter.StatisticsClassException:
> Statistics classes mismatched: class
> org.apache.iotdb.tsfile.file.metadata.statistics.IntegerStatistics vs.
> class.

Does anyone know what reason this error may occur in Apache IoTDB?

I imported the data tsfile from one IoTDB server to another IoTDB server, but it failed to load. Is there a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your field type is wrong to cause this error in Apache IoTDB. You can check if the two servers use the same version, and also set the same type of data parameters.